# code snippet works when procedural, but doesn't when converted to modular

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
function sc_HTMLParser(aHTMLString){
    var parseDOM = content.document.createElement('div');
    parseDOM.appendChild(Components.classes['@mozilla.org/feed-unescapehtml;1']
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML)
        .parseFragment(aHTMLString, false, null, parseDOM));
    return parseDOM;
}
```

becomes

```
this.HTMLParser = function(aHTMLString){
    var parseDOM = content.document.createElement('div');
    parseDOM.appendChild(Components.classes['@mozilla.org/feed-unescapehtml;1']
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML)
        .parseFragment(aHTMLString, false, null, parseDOM));
    return parseDOM;
}
```

and

```
searchcontents = req.responseText;
parsedHTML = sc_HTMLParser(searchcontents);
sitefound = sc_sitefound(compareuris, parsedHTML);
```

becomes

```
searchcontents = req.responseText;
alert(searchcontents);
parsedHTML = this.HTMLParser(searchcontents);
alert(parsedHTML);
sitefound = this.sitefound(compareuris, parsedHTML);
```

The modular code alerts the search contents, but doesn't alert the parsedHTML. Why? How to solve?

UPDATED:

j0rd4n, it's:

```
function SiteCompare() {
    this.finishSiteCompare = function(downloaduris, compareuris, tryinguri) {
        // code
        searchcontents = req.responseText;
        alert(searchcontents);
        parsedHTML = this.HTMLParser(searchcontents);
        alert(parsedHTML);
        sitefound = this.sitefound(compareuris, parsedHTML);
        // code
    }
    this.HTMLParser = function(aHTMLString) {
        //code
    }
}
```

The call is not even being made.

UPDATE:

the Error Console says this.HTMLParser is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not the same in the function definition and when it's being called.  When `HTMLParser` is defined, this is the `SiteCompare` object, when `this.HTMLParser(searchContents)` is called, `this` is probably the window object.  So the error you are getting means that `window.HTMLParser` is not a function.

To fix this you'd need to define your `HTMLParser` method outside of the `SiteCompare` object, or (probably better) use the `SiteCompare` object to call `HTMLParser`.  Example:

```
var parser = new SiteCompare();
parsedHTML = parser.HTMLParser(searchcontents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your calling logic executed in the same function-scope as the this.HTMLParser definition?

Try putting an alert statement inside of HTMLParser and see if the call is even made.  It sounds like it is throwing an exception and leaving your script.

Comment: rosscj2533 answered it correctly.  'this' refers to your SiteCompare object but the HTMLParser function is not defined as a member of that object (so it technically doesn't exist).  You need to either move it back as a global or define it as a member of the SiteCompare object.